# Export script for illustrator to save for web jpg

Tags: javascript, export, jpeg, adobe-illustrator

Can anyone help me write a script for illustrator CC2017 that Export files to web (legacy) as JPG then save the file and close after. I have 700 files each with 2 art boards and it would be painful to click file>Export>Save For Web(legacy) then right the file name and save the file then close.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've been trying for 2 days but all the codes i did is crap and wont work! i'm not really experienced with js

Comment: I might recommend a tutorial like https://www.w3schools.com/js/ then instead of asking here.

Comment: I'm studying on edx.org better than w3schools.com but thought to give it a shot might find someone would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script as per your requirement. I have just updated Script 1 to match your requirement. By default it assumes ruler is in Points and convert it into inches and use in the file name. You can add more check to handle other ruler units. This will have a-z if artboards are not more than 26 in case artboards are more than 26, it will show something else. Using ASCII code for this

```
var folder = Folder.selectDialog();
if (folder) {
    var files = folder.getFiles("*.ai");
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var currentFile = files[i];
        app.open(currentFile);
        var activeDocument = app.activeDocument;
        var jpegFolder = Folder(currentFile.path + "/JPG");
        if (!jpegFolder.exists)
            jpegFolder.create();
        var codeStart = 97; // for a;
        for (var j = 0; j < activeDocument.artboards.length; j++) {
            var activeArtboard = activeDocument.artboards[j];
            activeDocument.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(j);
            var bounds = activeArtboard.artboardRect;
            var left = bounds[0];
            var top = bounds[1];
            var right = bounds[2];
            var bottom = bounds[3];
            var width = right - left;
            var height = top - bottom;
            if (app.activeDocument.rulerUnits == RulerUnits.Points) { //Add more if for more conversions
                width = width / 72;
                height = height / 72;
            }
            var fileName = activeDocument.name.split('.')[0] + "-" + String.fromCharCode(codeStart) + "-" + width + "x" + height + ".jpg";
            var destinationFile = File(jpegFolder + "/" + fileName);
            var type = ExportType.JPEG;
            var options = new ExportOptionsJPEG();
            options.antiAliasing = true;
            options.artBoardClipping = true;
            options.optimization = true;
            options.qualitySetting = 100; // Set Quality Setting
            activeDocument.exportFile(destinationFile, type, options);
            codeStart++;
        }
        activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
        currentFile = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is on problem here, i think its with the math if the artboard is 1.5 inch the script will display it as 2 inchs

Comment: Yes because we are using round method. It will round to next digit. So you wants as 1.5??

Comment: Yes please, would like to keep the exact size for the art board. even as 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Here is the javascript code that will export all ai files present in the selected folder into a jpg. This code will ask you to select a folder. So select folder that will have 700 files

**Script 1: Using JPEGQuality**

```
var folder = Folder.selectDialog();
if (folder) {
    var files = folder.getFiles("*.ai");
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var currentFile = files[i];
        app.open(currentFile);
        var activeDocument = app.activeDocument;
        var jpegFolder = Folder(currentFile.path + "/JPG");
        if (!jpegFolder.exists)
            jpegFolder.create();
        for (var j = 0; j < activeDocument.artboards.length; j++) {
            var activeArtboard = activeDocument.artboards[0];
            activeDocument.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(j);
            var fileName = activeDocument.name.split('.')[0] + "Artboard" + (j + 1) + ".jpg";
            var destinationFile = File(jpegFolder + "/" + fileName);
            var type = ExportType.JPEG;
            var options = new ExportOptionsJPEG();
            options.antiAliasing = true;
            options.artBoardClipping = true;
            options.optimization = true;
            options.qualitySetting = 100; // Set Quality Setting
            activeDocument.exportFile(destinationFile, type, options);
        }
        activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
        currentFile = null;
    }
}
```

Since you have two artboards in each ai file. It will create two separate jpg for each artboard. You can change file name and folder location for jpg images as per requirement.

**Script 2: By changing resolution**

```
var folder = Folder.selectDialog();
if (folder) {
    var files = folder.getFiles("*.ai");
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var currentFile = files[i];
        app.open(currentFile);
        var activeDocument = app.activeDocument;
        var jpegFolder = Folder(currentFile.path + "/JPG");
        if (!jpegFolder.exists)
            jpegFolder.create();
        var fileName = activeDocument.name.split('.')[0] + ".jpg";
        var destinationFile = File(jpegFolder + "/" + fileName);
        // Export Artboard where you can set resolution for an image. Set to 600 by default in code.
        var opts = new ImageCaptureOptions();
        opts.resolution = 600;
        opts.antiAliasing = true;
        opts.transparency = true;
        try {
            activeDocument.imageCapture(new File(destinationFile), activeDocument.geometricBounds, opts);
        } catch (e) {

        }
        activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
        currentFile = null;
    }
}
```

For script 2, there will be only single file for one ai file, irrespective of the artboards.
SO you can run both script for your work and go ahead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! it works perfect, but how can i choose the jpg quality I want to make sure its 100%  and is it easy to use letters for the name instead of  numbers    ` "Artboard" + (j + 1) `

Comment: Most welcome dear. I have edited the code above to have jpeg quality using property qualitySetting. There is another way also export into jpeg where you can set a resolution for an image. But higher the resolution processing will be slow but image quality will be good. So you can use any way that suits your requirement.

Comment: I have edited my answer and suggested you with two different scripts.For names of the file, you can change accordingly as required. Or you just let me know how you want names of jpgs. Hope my new answers will help you in your work.

Comment: Dude this is awesome! the First script seems to work perfect, what does `options.qualitySetting = 100;` mean ? 100%...  
If you can change the name to be ( file name + **a** + **artboard size** ) or **b** or **c** depends how many artboards in there. If adding the artboard size is hard then forget about it but wold be great to have it there. also you can use hyphen like (file-name-a-11x17.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, yes **options.qualitySetting = 100 means 100%**. Yes, we can change the name of the filename like **(filename + a + artboard size),** but my concern is a-z are 26 characters, in case any file will have more than 26 artboards then what you want next for 27th artboard in place a, b or c and so on?

Comment: I have 700 ai files and each file wont have more than 5 Artboards so don't worry about using more than 5 characters. There's a problem with the script  it save all the **ai** files even if i didn't open them, The file name is working perfectly but the size is not. its giving the same size for all artboards and add 000000 at the end like this **(750x620.00000000001)** we can skip where i want to save the jpg's and have it save in the same parent folder by default.

Comment: See,  Here are the points, It will save all ai files present in the selected folder, if you want less you can copy only those files that you want to process in the separate folder and select this new folder. For artboard size, I think ai file ruler units is not Points so it's showing you wrong if you can tell me what are the units used in your documents then will change accordingly. In case you want to remove artboard size from file name just replace this one line

var fileName = activeDocument.name.split('.')[0] + "-" + String.fromCharCode(codeStart) +  ".jpg";

Comment: all the files will be using points or pixels, when i tested the script i checked the unit before and it was points but still got the same result! I would like to keep the name and size because there will too many different sizes.

Comment: I have edited my script. Please check, just edited one line. Also, I am not able to get an issue that artboard size is coming as 750x620.00000000001. If size is in Points then it will definitely work but for pixels, it will not because there is no check for pixels in the script. You can add easily.

Comment: now the script save only one artboard and duplicate it 3 times, and the name problem (**250x250.000000001**) is from the artboard size so dont worry about it. I would suggest to go back to the first script because it worked the best. email me if you want arsaar7@gmail .. thank you

Comment: Updated script. See resolve artboard duplicate issue. For size, I will recommend you to mail your ai file on charurajput89@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

VBA example that uses one Excel-specific statement

```
Sub Export_All()
Dim fs As Object
Dim aiRef As Object
Dim docRef As Object
Dim jpegExportOptions As Object
Dim f As Object
Dim p As String

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set aiRef = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application")
    Set jpegExportOptions = CreateObject("Illustrator.ExportOptionsJPEG")

    ' Specify all export options here
    jpegExportOptions.AntiAliasing = False
    jpegExportOptions.QualitySetting = 70

    p = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path         ' Excel-specific.  You may change it to whatever you like

    For Each f In fs.GetFolder(p).Files
        If LCase(Right(f.Name, 3) = ".ai") Then
            Debug.Print f.Name
            Set docRef = aiRef.Open(p + "\" + f.Name)
            Call docRef.Export(p + "\" + f.Name + ".jpg", 1, jpegExportOptions)
            Set docRef = Nothing
        End If
    Next

    ' Note that AI is still open and invisible
End Sub
```

Comment: Why js?! Open Excel, paste and run!

Comment: because I can add the script to the ai files and run it from the File menu. I tried this code you provided using Visual Studio Code but didn't work. not sure if i did it right. This is so far what i came up with
    [Script](https://jsfiddle.net/y4kpqydc/)

Comment: Try Excel.  Paste this code to a code VBA module.  Save XLS to the same folder where your AI files are located