# Convert an AI file into a JPG image using PHP

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, adobe-illustrator

Is there a programmatic way (say through PHP or C++) to input an AI file (all assets: layers, copy, images, fonts, etc), and output a JPG image?

Comment: try changing the `.ai` to `.pdf` and try opening the file. if you are able to open the file then you can convert pdf to jpeg

Comment: Or try [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970036/export-script-for-illustrator-to-save-for-web-jpg)